# Knockout Mapping - fromJS - failing on a simple example

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to figure out what I'm misunderstanding with Knockout's mapping library. I've stripped it down to a simple example, and still can get it to fail (rather, not update with the mapped variables) with the `fromJS` call.

What am I getting fundamentally wrong in this example?

```
// Here's my view model
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('first');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('last');
};

var myVM = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(myVM); // Apply to Knockout (works)

myVM.lastName('maiden name'); // Test an update (works)

var newData = {firstName: 'new', lastName: 'person'};

// Try update the ViewModel
ko.mapping.fromJS(newData, myVM); //(No update, or error)

// Intended result - UI updates to 'new person'
```

And the corresponding view:

```
<div class='liveExample' >   
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
</div>
```

My [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QJNTY/4/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ko.mapping.fromJS` handles the parameters a little bit tricky (see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322804/unable-to-parse-bindings-js-error-using-ko-mapping-fromjson-with-parse-exist-vie/13324185#13324185)), so the second parameter is normally the mapping options:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(newData, {} /* mapping options */, myVM);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTm8z/).

Comment: Tricky indeed! I would've been struggling like @Overflew

Comment: Thanks @nemesv. The Knockout Mapping docs at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html certainly sent me down the wrong path. I'm re-reading them, still trying to understand which context it's correct to call the 2-param version...

Comment: Ah, I get it now - Thanks for your 1/2/3 argument explanation in your other linked answer.

Answer (score 7):

I found how to use only 2 data parameters.

Create your ViewModel as a *mapping* of your original data, then use `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ViewModel)`.

UPDATED [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJNTY/5/)

**Explanation**

Knockout uses a property called `mappingProperty = "__ko_mapping__"` to identify when data has been previously mapped. If found, it will set the second parameter as the target (ViewModel in this case).

Excerpt from the debug version of *ko.mapping.js*:

```
var mappingProperty = "__ko_mapping__";

[...]

if (arguments.length == 2) {
  if (arguments[1][mappingProperty]) {
    target = arguments[1];
  } else {
    options = arguments[1];
  }
}
```