# how to use knockout mapping plugin?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I want to use plugin to populate data, but values are not populated.

Simple example:

```
var data = {
    Type: 1,
    Id: "123-12321"
};

var RiskItemModel = function (item) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable("tes");
    self.Type = ko.observable(); //enum int


    if (item) {
      // DATA SHOULD BE POPULATED HERE, but no effect
      ko.mapping.fromJS(item, this);
    };
};

var model = new RiskItemModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(model);

// I HAVE TRIED THIS ALSO, NO EFFECT
//ko.mapping.fromJS(data, model);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

JSFidde: http://jsfiddle.net/wLbV6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using the correct overload of the `ko.mapping.fromJS` function.

You need to write:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(item, {} /* mapping options */, this);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cShjN/).

`ko.mapping.fromJS` function only works with supping only two parameters if the second parameter is an object which was already mapped by the plugin so it has the `"__ko_mapping__"` property.

You can read more about the different overloads here: [Unable to parse bindings js error using ko.mapping.fromJSON with parse exist view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322804/unable-to-parse-bindings-js-error-using-ko-mapping-fromjson-with-parse-exist-vie/13324185#13324185)